# How to fix the layout, that keeps aligning to the right

Tags: html, css, angular

I am building a checkout page for a e-commerce store and the elements keep aligning to the right. The css file of this specific component is empty, I'm using only global css for the entire project. In other pages the Angular's flexLayout module is behaving as supposed to, just this page the alignment is right no matter what I do.

I tried fully and partially remove the HTML-code from the container and even the container itself, any kind of data that goes on this specific page aligns to the right.
I tried to override it somehow by placing 'justify-content: flex-start!important; ' in component's CSS

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">

    <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start" fxLayout="column" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkoutForm.value)">
        <h3>Cart</h3>
          <div>
            <label>Credit Card Owner Name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name">
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Credit Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="credit_number">
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Cell Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="phone">
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="address">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button (click)="addOrder(name.value, credit_number.value, phone.value, address.value)"
            class="btn btn-primary">
              Purchase
            </button>
          </div>

        </form>

      <div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="40%" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">

        <p>
          <a routerLink="/shipping">Shipping Prices</a>
        </p>

        <div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
          <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-item" >
          <span style="font-weight: bold">TOTAL</span>
          <span style="font-weight: bold"> {{ cartService.calculateTotal() | currency }}</span>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get the solution fast and accurate, could you please share more information like a screenshot of how the page is currently looking and the expected layout (how it should look). Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. :) Would it be possible for you share a minimal working example replicating this issue?